# Issue building Tensorflow using Bazel (Windows) => to use Tensorflow C++ API

Tags: c++, tensorflow, build, bazel

My initial goal was simply to use Tensorflow's C++ API to read a ".pb" frozen model and make predictions with it. Was using Keras to prototype it, managed to freeze the model and try it with Tensorflow on Python ; everything goes smoothly.
So i basically JUST need the C++ API to work.

I'm using an i5-8400T computer, no GPU, 8GB ram. All versions of bazel and tensorflow were downloaded today (27/08/2019).

First thing I did was to follow [tensorflow's guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/extend/cc) of course. Ran the little `bazel run -c opt //tensorflow/cc/example:example`, and that... several times.

First time, needed to downgrade my bazel version to `0.26.1` to make tensorflow's `configure.py` happy.

Then I had the same problem as a few people had apparently, which is an error fetching `io_bazel_rules_docker`, which then stops the rest of the build of course. (what follows is what i got as an output here)

---

```
bazel : INFO: Options provided by the client:
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
+ bazel run -c opt //tensorflow/cc/example:example > error.txt 2>&1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (INFO: Options provided by the client::String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

  Inherited 'common' options: --isatty=0 --terminal_columns=80

INFO: Options provided by the client:
  Inherited 'build' options: --python_path=C:/Users/IMEDSYS/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/python.exe

INFO: Reading rc options for 'run' from c:\users\imedsys\bin\tensorflow\.bazelrc:
  Inherited 'build' options: --apple_platform_type=macos --define framework_shared_object=true --define 
open_source_build=true --define=use_fast_cpp_protos=true --define=allow_oversize_protos=true 
--spawn_strategy=standalone --strategy=Genrule=standalone -c opt --cxxopt=-std=c++14 --host_cxxopt=-std=c++14 
--announce_rc --define=grpc_no_ares=true --define=PREFIX=/usr --define=LIBDIR=$(PREFIX)/lib 
--define=INCLUDEDIR=$(PREFIX)/include

INFO: Reading rc options for 'run' from c:\users\imedsys\bin\tensorflow\.tf_configure.bazelrc:
  Inherited 'build' options: --action_env 
PYTHON_BIN_PATH=C:/Users/IMEDSYS/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/python.exe --action_env 
PYTHON_LIB_PATH=C:/Users/IMEDSYS/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/lib/site-packages 
--python_path=C:/Users/IMEDSYS/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/python.exe --config monolithic --copt=-w 
--host_copt=-w --copt=-DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN --host_copt=-DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN --copt=-DNOGDI --host_copt=-DNOGDI 
--verbose_failures --distinct_host_configuration=false --action_env TF_CONFIGURE_IOS=0

INFO: Found applicable config definition build:monolithic in file c:\users\imedsys\bin\tensorflow\.bazelrc: --define 
framework_shared_object=false

Loading: 

Loading: 0 packages loaded

INFO: Call stack for the definition of repository 'io_bazel_rules_docker' which is a git_repository (rule definition 
at C:/users/imedsys/_bazel_imedsys/wmdtvioi/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/git.bzl:252:18):
 - C:/users/imedsys/_bazel_imedsys/wmdtvioi/external/bazel_toolchains/repositories/repositories.bzl:37:9
 - C:/users/imedsys/bin/tensorflow/WORKSPACE:35:1

ERROR: An error occurred during the fetch of repository 'io_bazel_rules_docker':
   Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:/users/imedsys/_bazel_imedsys/wmdtvioi/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/git.bzl", line 234
        _clone_or_update(ctx)
    File "C:/users/imedsys/_bazel_imedsys/wmdtvioi/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/git.bzl", line 74, in 
_clone_or_update
        fail(("error cloning %s:\n%s" % (ctx....)))
error cloning io_bazel_rules_docker:
fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /mnt)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
/bin/bash: line 1: cd: C:/users/imedsys/_bazel_imedsys/wmdtvioi/external: No such file or directory
+ cd C:/users/imedsys/_bazel_imedsys/wmdtvioi/external
/bin/bash: line 3: cd: C:/users/imedsys/_bazel_imedsys/wmdtvioi/external: No such file or directory
+ git -C C:/users/imedsys/_bazel_imedsys/wmdtvioi/external/io_bazel_rules_docker reset --hard 
251f6a68b439744094faff800cd029798edf9faa
fatal: cannot change to 'C:/users/imedsys/_bazel_imedsys/wmdtvioi/external/io_bazel_rules_docker': No such file or 
directory
+ git -C C:/users/imedsys/_bazel_imedsys/wmdtvioi/external/io_bazel_rules_docker fetch '' origin 
251f6a68b439744094faff800cd029798edf9faa:251f6a68b439744094faff800cd029798edf9faa
fatal: cannot change to 'C:/users/imedsys/_bazel_imedsys/wmdtvioi/external/io_bazel_rules_docker': No such file or 
directory
+ git -C C:/users/imedsys/_bazel_imedsys/wmdtvioi/external/io_bazel_rules_docker fetch origin 
251f6a68b439744094faff800cd029798edf9faa:251f6a68b439744094faff800cd029798edf9faa
fatal: cannot change to 'C:/users/imedsys/_bazel_imedsys/wmdtvioi/external/io_bazel_rules_docker': No such file or 
directory

ERROR: ... *idem*

ERROR: ... *idem*

INFO: Elapsed time: 2.346s

INFO: 0 processes.

FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded)

ERROR: Build failed. Not running target

FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded)

***
```

I so tried applying what [this issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/28824) was offering, which involves going to the [rules_docker](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_docker) repository and replace targets with the latest ones.

The thing is even after this you get the same kind of errors with the protobuf targets, which I get hash errors for if i apply the same strategy.

I then tried to do it with CMake as many were saying last year that bazel building on windows was not yet usable. I used two similar guides, one of them [here](http://mc.ai/building-tensorflow-c-shared-library-on-windows/), and so tried to build with

```
cmake .. -A x64 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DSWIG_EXECUTABLE=C:\swigwin-3.0.12\swig.exe -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\python.exe -DPYTHON_LIBRARIES=C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\libs\python35.lib
```

at first, and then with

```
`cmake .. -A x64 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DSWIG_EXECUTABLE=C:\swigwin-3.0.12\swig.exe -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\python.exe -DPYTHON_LIBRARIES=C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\libs\python35.lib -Dtensorflow_BUILD_PYTHON_BINDINGS=OFF -Dtensorflow_ENABLE_GRPC_SUPPORT=OFF -Dtensorflow_BUILD_SHARED_LIB=ON`
```

and i get those errors :

---

```
cmake : CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:9 (message):
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
+ cmake .. -A x64 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DSWIG_EXECUTABLE=C:\Users ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (CMake Warning a...xt:9 (message)::String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

  Your current cmake generator is set to use 32 bit toolset architecture.

  This may cause "compiler out of heap space" errors when building.  Consider

  using the flag -Thost=x64 when running cmake.  Ignore this if you are on

  CMake GUI.



-- Selecting Windows SDK version  to target Windows 10.0.17763.
-- C:/Users/IMEDSYS/bin/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/cmake/build/abseil_cpp/src/abseil_cpp_build
-- Configuring done
CMake Error at tf_core_ops.cmake:77 (add_library):

  Cannot find source file:

    C:/Users/IMEDSYS/bin/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/factorization/ops/clustering_ops.cc

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .cu .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm

  .hpp .hxx .in .txx

Call Stack (most recent call first):

  tf_core_ops.cmake:95 (GENERATE_CONTRIB_OP_LIBRARY)

  CMakeLists.txt:594 (include)



CMake Error at tf_core_ops.cmake:77 (add_library):

  Cannot find source file:

    C:/Users/IMEDSYS/bin/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/ops/gru_ops.cc

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .cu .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm

  .hpp .hxx .in .txx

Call Stack (most recent call first):

  tf_core_ops.cmake:107 (GENERATE_CONTRIB_OP_LIBRARY)

  CMakeLists.txt:594 (include)



CMake Error at tf_core_ops.cmake:77 (add_library):

  Cannot find source file:

    C:/Users/IMEDSYS/bin/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/ops/lstm_ops.cc
  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .cu .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm

  .hpp .hxx .in .txx

Call Stack (most recent call first):

  tf_core_ops.cmake:108 (GENERATE_CONTRIB_OP_LIBRARY)

  CMakeLists.txt:594 (include)



CMake Error at tf_core_kernels.cmake:205 (add_library):

  Cannot find source file:

    C:/Users/IMEDSYS/bin/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/factorization/kernels/clustering_ops.cc

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .cu .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm

  .hpp .hxx .in .txx

Call Stack (most recent call first):

  CMakeLists.txt:596 (include)



CMake Error at tf_core_ops.cmake:77 (add_library):

  No SOURCES given to target: tf_contrib_factorization_clustering_ops

Call Stack (most recent call first):

  tf_core_ops.cmake:95 (GENERATE_CONTRIB_OP_LIBRARY)

  CMakeLists.txt:594 (include)



CMake Error at tf_core_ops.cmake:77 (add_library):

  No SOURCES given to target: tf_contrib_rnn_gru_ops
Call Stack (most recent call first):

  tf_core_ops.cmake:107 (GENERATE_CONTRIB_OP_LIBRARY)

  CMakeLists.txt:594 (include)



CMake Error at tf_core_ops.cmake:77 (add_library):

  No SOURCES given to target: tf_contrib_rnn_lstm_ops

Call Stack (most recent call first):

  tf_core_ops.cmake:108 (GENERATE_CONTRIB_OP_LIBRARY)

  CMakeLists.txt:594 (include)



CMake Error at tf_core_ops.cmake:77 (add_library):

  No SOURCES given to target: tf_contrib_tpu_ops

Call Stack (most recent call first):

  tf_core_ops.cmake:115 (GENERATE_CONTRIB_OP_LIBRARY)

  CMakeLists.txt:594 (include)



CMake Error at tf_core_kernels.cmake:205 (add_library):

  No SOURCES given to target: tf_core_kernels

Call Stack (most recent call first):

  CMakeLists.txt:596 (include)



CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.
```

---

This time i feel like it's simply that CMake looks for files that are either depreciated, either relocated.

## SO,

my questions is rather simple :

- does someone has 2 version numbers of both bazel and tensorflow that actually work together (because it seems that it does work for some people => I consider trying voodoo)?
- does someone has a very straightforward solution to use Tensorflow's c_api or C++ API ?
- does someone knows another way to make a prediction with either Keras or Tensorflow outputs (.hdf5 or .pb) from a C++ built software, without doing as disgusting as "system("python predict.py")"?

---

Thank you in advance for your quick answers! :)

Comment: Thks! Didn't know how to do it ^^'

Answer (score 0):

I  had done similar work building  older Tensorflow version (not 2.) for VS 2017 using Cmake.

Cuda 9 . Tensorflow 1.14  VS 2017  .

Comment: I built Tensorflow 1.14 as well, but got issues with CMake. VS2015. But no CUDA as I don't have any GPU. But I'm gonna try again I guess.. maybe it's the version of CMake that is the issue?

Comment: I think so, you can check here for version  compatibility https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows